# Load JavaScript file inside another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, node.js

I'm using `node.js` and `socket.io` and doing a server/client thing. On my Server, is since its' not on a webpage, is there a way I can load the latest file (or latest jQuery?) so I can use jQuery functions inside my Server js file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install jQuery on your server like that:

```
npm install jquery
```

And then you need to declare your jQuery variable like this:

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
```

Now you can use jQuery like you are used too. More information [here](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery).

Comment: My second line of code will load it. Put it in the top of your server.js for example. It’s build like a Node.js module, like Express and so on…

Comment: OK, I did it. It says it cannot find module `location`.

Comment: prob, you giving wrong path for jquery. change this line //var $ = require('jQuery');

Comment: Be sure to install the module with npm. My first line of code. You have to do it on your computer/server etc. Npm is a tool to manage Node modules.

Comment: I did install it. I had to drag the folder, though, from a place to my wamp folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can load it as text and `eval(jquery)` will let you use jquery

Comment: if you eval a js text like eval("var jq=function(){return 4;}"); this will let you use jq function. So you can use it for jquery file. But if there is plug-in for jq ofcourse its better usage. But this is less code =D